# Use IF() Null Coalesce in SQL Parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to use the If() Operator to coalesce values in a SQL Parameter but I am having trouble figured it out.

```
Dim First as String = Nothing
First = FirstName.Text
Using conn As New SqlConnection()
'Code omitted
.AddWithValue("@FirstName", If(First, DBNull.Value))
```

Basically, if First = Nothing, the Parameter should be formatted like:

```
.AddWithValue("@FirstName", DBNull.Value)
```

If FirstName.Text is not `Nothing` or `Null` then it would basically be like:

```
.AddWithValue("@FirstName", First)
```

Anyone have any pointers or have any suggestions?

I understand that First is carrying a value of `""`, I am just not sure how to program around that. That's why I tried `= Nothing`.

This is currently being written like:

```
If employeeName <> "last,first" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPL_NM", employeeName)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPL_NM", DBNull.Value)
End If
```

Which I'm trying to reduce to

```
.AddWithValue("@FirstName", If(First, DBNull.Value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBNull.Value` and `String` are different types. The null-coalescing operator doesn't like that.

You could cast it to `Object` to make it compile, although i would prefer your `If-Else`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", If(First, DirectCast(DBNull.Value, Object)))
```

Comment: Damnet. I thought it would have something to do with that. Thanks! Do you think the `If/Else` is more efficient?

Comment: @Newbie: it's not more efficient but it's clear and also enables to write additional code, for example if you want to handle the case that `First` is `Nothing` (message-box, log etc).